# Import CSV File and Doing arithmetic Opertions without importing any Library in PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My CSV file Looks Like this

```
Time_stamp; Mobile_number; Download; Upload; Connection_start_time; Connection_end_time; location
1/2/2020 10:43:55;+917777777777;213455;2343;1/2/2020 10:43:55;1/2/2020 10:47:25;09443
1/3/2020 10:33:10;+919999999999;345656;3568;1/3/2020 10:33:10;1/3/2020 10:37:20;89442
1/4/2020 11:47:57;+919123456654;345789;7651;1/4/2020 11:11:10;1/4/2020 11:40:22;19441
1/5/2020 11:47:57;+919123456543;342467;4157;1/5/2020 11:44:10;1/5/2020 11:59:22;29856
1/6/2020 10:47:57;+917777777777;213455;2343;1/6/2020 10:43:55;1/6/2020 10:47:25;09443
```

MY Question is
Without importing any Library file
How i can read a CSV file & user have to enter the Mobile number & Program should show the Data usage of that number. ie: Arithmetic Operation (Adding Uplink & downlink ) & get the result (Total Data Used)of that specific Mobile number.

Here is what my code looks Like. ( i don't want to import any Pandas Library. )

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns]
usage = df[['Download', 'Upload']][df.Mobile_number == +917777777777].sum().sum()
print(usage)
```

Comment: that's impossible. even pandas uses other libraries, which are built into python. why do you have such a task?

Comment: You can use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) (from the standard library) to read the file.

Comment: using the csv.reader how i can do it

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of  [How to read a csv file and sum values based on user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670042/how-to-read-a-csv-file-and-sum-values-based-on-user-input) by the same OP.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use csv.DictReader

```
In [30]: with open('x', 'r') as f:
    ...:     r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    ...:     dct = {}
    ...:     for row in r:
    ...:         dct.setdefault(row[' Mobile_number'], []).append(row)
    ...:

In [31]: dct
Out[31]:
{'+917777777777': [OrderedDict([('Time_stamp', '1/2/2020 10:43:55'),
               (' Mobile_number', '+917777777777'),
               (' Download', '213455'),
               (' Upload', '2343'),
               (' Connection_start_time', '1/2/2020 10:43:55'),
               (' Connection_end_time', '1/2/2020 10:47:25'),
               (' location', '09443')]),
  OrderedDict([('Time_stamp', '1/6/2020 10:47:57'),
               (' Mobile_number', '+917777777777'),
               (' Download', '213455'),
               (' Upload', '2343'),
               (' Connection_start_time', '1/6/2020 10:43:55'),
               (' Connection_end_time', '1/6/2020 10:47:25'),
               (' location', '09443')])],
 '+919999999999': [OrderedDict([('Time_stamp', '1/3/2020 10:33:10'),
               (' Mobile_number', '+919999999999'),
               (' Download', '345656'),
               (' Upload', '3568'),
               (' Connection_start_time', '1/3/2020 10:33:10'),
               (' Connection_end_time', '1/3/2020 10:37:20'),
               (' location', '89442')])],
 '+919123456654': [OrderedDict([('Time_stamp', '1/4/2020 11:47:57'),
               (' Mobile_number', '+919123456654'),
               (' Download', '345789'),
               (' Upload', '7651'),
               (' Connection_start_time', '1/4/2020 11:11:10'),
               (' Connection_end_time', '1/4/2020 11:40:22'),
               (' location', '19441')])],
 '+919123456543': [OrderedDict([('Time_stamp', '1/5/2020 11:47:57'),
               (' Mobile_number', '+919123456543'),
               (' Download', '342467'),
               (' Upload', '4157'),
               (' Connection_start_time', '1/5/2020 11:44:10'),
               (' Connection_end_time', '1/5/2020 11:59:22'),
               (' location', '29856')])]}

In [32]:
```

You then process list of dict for a given mobile number by something like `usage = sum(float(_[' Download']) + float(_[' Upload']) for _ in dct['+91777777777'])`

Answer (score 0):

Noting that you specifically wanted to avoid importing *any* libraries (I assume this means you want to avoid importing even from the included modules) - for a trivial file (I named one supermarkets.csv, the content looks like this):

> ID,Address,City,State,Country,Name,Employees
>   1,3666 21st St,San Francisco,CA 94114,USA,Madeira,8
>   2,735 Dolores St,San Francisco,CA 94119,USA,Bready Shop,15
>   3,332 Hill St,San Francisco,California 94114,USA,Super River,25
>   4,3995 23rd St,San Francisco,CA 94114,USA,Ben's Shop,10
>   5,1056 Sanchez St,San Francisco,California,USA,Sanchez,12
>   6,551 Alvarado St,San Francisco,CA 94114,USA,Richvalley,20

Then you can do something like this:

```
data = []
with open("supermarkets.csv") as f:
        for line in f:
        data.append(line)
print(data)
```

From here you can manipulate your each of the entries in the list using string tools and list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `open` that does not require any library, to read your file and then iterate through it with `readlines`. Split the line and check your condition depending on the place in the file your data are.

```
usage=0
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        try:
            line_sp = line.split(';')
            if line_sp[1]=='+917777777777':
                usage += int(line_sp[2])+int(line_sp[3])
        except:
            #print(line)
            pass 
print (usage)
```

Comment: line 5, in <module>
    if line_sp[1]=='+917777777777':
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: it would be that input line is not the ';' delimited line. For example, if you have empty line added at the end you'd see this error.   You may want to test if line_sp has 6 elements as expected, and if not print line and telling that cannot process this line, somethign like that.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed see the edit with try except, if you want to see what is the error in the lines un-comment the print to see the line, but otherwise it should work

Comment: @MohamedAhmed I tried with the data you gave and got 431596 which is the same value than your piece of code give me too withsame sample of data, so I can't reproduce your probelm. Maybe before the `try`, can you add `print(line)` and see if the delimiter is wrong, or paste in the comment the result of a print with the right Mobile Number you want to calculate

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can fit your use case:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
d= defaultdict(list)
with open('data.txt',newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace = True)
    headers = reader.fieldnames
    for row in reader: 
        row['Usage'] = int(row['Upload']) + int(row['Download'])
        d[row.get('Mobile_number')].append(row["Usage"])

print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {'+917777777777': [215798, 215798],
             '+919999999999': [349224],
             '+919123456654': [353440],
             '+919123456543': [346624]})

#get sum for specific mobile number : 
sum(d.get("+917777777777"))
431596
```

Additional details :

```
new_d = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    kb = sum(v)
    mb = kb/1024
    gb = kb/1024**2
    usage = F"{kb}KB/{mb:.2f}MB/{gb:.2f}GB"
    new_d[k] = usage

print(new_d)
{'+917777777777': '431596KB/421.48MB/0.41GB',
 '+919999999999': '349224KB/341.04MB/0.33GB',
 '+919123456654': '353440KB/345.16MB/0.34GB',
 '+919123456543': '346624KB/338.50MB/0.33GB'}
```

Comment: when i use print(sum(d.get("+919999999999"))) Dosen't Show the amount 431596

Comment: what does it give u?

Comment: my file name is log.csv (not a txt file)
i want to get the output like

Enter the Mobile Number to get the usage: 
     user inputs: +917777777777

Total Monthly Usage is: 431596 KB / 421.48MB / 0.41GB

Comment: sure, it can be rearranged. but does the sum work for just usage?

Answer (score 0):

### Using no imported modules

```py
# read file and create dict of phone numbers
phone_dict = dict()
with open('test.csv') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        l = l.strip().split(';')
        if (i != 0):
            mobile = l[1]
            download = int(l[2])
            upload = int(l[3])
            if phone_dict.get(mobile) == None:
                phone_dict[mobile] = {'download': [download], 'upload': [upload]}
            else:
                phone_dict[mobile]['download'].append(download)
                phone_dict[mobile]['upload'].append(upload)


print(phone_dict)
{'+917777777777': {'download': [213455, 213455], 'upload': [2343, 2343]},
 '+919999999999': {'download': [345656], 'upload': [3568]},
 '+919123456654': {'download': [345789], 'upload': [7651]},
 '+919123456543': {'download': [342467], 'upload': [4157]}}

# function to return usage
def return_usage(data: dict, number: str):
    download_usage = sum(data[number]['download'])
    upload_usage = sum(data[number]['upload'])

    return download_usage + upload_usage

# get user input to return usage
number = input('Please input a phone number')

usage = return_usage(phone_dict, number)
print(usage)
>>> Please input a phone number (numbers only) +917777777777
>>> 431596
```